# When should I use my display's native gamma over the standard 2.2?

Tags: color-management, gamma

When it comes to color management and calibration, reading in official/unofficial sources, there are different oppinions telling that the native display gamma value can be left "as is" = "native" (2.43 measured in my case)

OR,

on the other hand, gamma value could be set at 2.2;
 
How can I approach this, which is the "right" seein color, at native monitor gamma value or other value (e.g. 2.2)? if the gamma have any influence in the viewing process excepting all the other variables (room light condition, color temperature, etc considering these the same in both cases).

—Official source: page 96,97 of [this book](https://books.google.ro/books?id=wcIdAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA96&ots=mrWNtg7afT&dq=x-rite%20native%20gamma&hl=ro&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=x-rite%20native%20gamma&f=false) for example.

—Another source [Argyll.com](http://www.argyllcms.com/doc/Scenarios.html#PM1b):
*Adjusting and Calibrating Displays*
By default, the brightness and white point will be kept the same as the devices natural brightness and white point. The default response curve is a gamma of 2.4, except for Apple OS X systems prior to 10.6 where a gamma of 1.8 is the default. **2.4** is close to that of  many monitors, and **close to that of the sRGB** colorspace.

—Another one dispcalGUI documentation:
*Why has a default gamma of 2.2 been chosen for some presets?*
Many displays, be it CRT, LCD, Plasma or OLED, have a default response characteristic close to a gamma of approx. 2.2-2.4. **A target response curve for calibration that is reasonably close to the native response of a display should help to minimize calibration artifacts like banding**, because the adjustments needed to the video card's gamma tables via calibration curves will not be as strong as if a target response farther away from the display's native response had been chosen.

Of course, you can and should change the calibration response curve to a value suitable for your own requirements. For example, you might have a display that offers hardware calibration or gamma controls, that has been internally calibrated/adjusted to a different response curve, **or your display's response is simply not close to a gamma of 2.2 for other reasons**. You can run “Report on uncalibrated display device” from the “Tools” menu to measure the approximated overall gamma among other info.

...

That's why I am still confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the standard gamma value?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41960/what-is-the-standard-gamma-value)

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for a standard gamma value. As I've explained above, I'm looking more for an elaborate answer, that could confirm the _native_ gamma value usage in different cases (like this one 2.43 over 2.2 not under the standard value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting display gamma to 2.2 or sRGB (in LCD OSD settings, that is) will make it closer to perceptually uniform (i.e. efficient for be used by human) and also make 8 bit images with gamma 2.2 or sRGB expose less banding (bigger colour depth) when viewed at 100%.

However, there is a problem, at least with DisplayCAL: creating profile for gamma 2.2 means that 1D LUT will be created. This 1D LUT can be applied in two ways:

- using videocard LUT (most oftenly 8bit -> 8bit)
- using display internal LUT (may have much bigger internal precision like 8bit -> 14bit)

Here comes the problem. Assume that you have an 8bit LCD which does not have gamma correction at all (or does not allow the gamma to be set enough closely to taget) and also does not use editable internal 1D LUT. If you calibrate your LCD for gamma 2.2 the DisplayCAL will make your LCD loose colour depth because it does not offer any interactive gamma adjustment. Therefore your LCD won't even be 8bit anymore (more like 7,5bit, for example).

If your entire workflow is 16bit there is zero sense in creating 1D LUT. However, since most LCDs have extra contrast, you may set your LCD gamma to compensate for it BEFORE profiling and then create profile for gamma "As measured".

Creating 1D LUT for video card (8bit to 8bit) will only cut your colour depth.

Comment: interesting feed-back thank you.My pretty old [Belinea P-MVA](http://goo.gl/NGwmt8), have—according to the technical feaflet—24-bit (which, as far as I understand it's 8-bit/channel).Indeed there is no internal LUT possibility and also there is no interactive gamma adjustment. At this point I'm pretty confused, but I suppose, you're trying to say that if our workflow is at 16-bit/channel and the monitor is limited at 8-bit/channel, the calibration process is useless—that's the point? Also, in your oppinion, should I let the monitor gamma value at 2.43 measured in my case?thanks

Comment: @user124853: yes, in case when you cannot tune LCD you should profile for native gamma. If you are working with 16bit images you won't loose anything.

Comment: make sense somehow but, Is there any possibility to visually check if the monitor allow the gamma to be set enough closely to target? running a measurement report after the dispcalGUI profile was loaded (assuming that we choose an sRGB 2.2 profile) I guess that could be shown any LCD limitation, am I right?  the LCD also allow to be set at sRGB but if measure this hardware setting, doesn't _look_ like dispcalGUI sRGB setpoint. Also do you have a source that approach much deeply this subject please?

Comment: @user124853: yes, you are right, you may review the tone response curves to see how bad your LCD is. You may open any profile tone response curves and compare them (just be sure to select proper viewing settings below). [Example](http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0316/h_1458124133_8762464_c9bbf91f00.png). The bigger slope around 0 means that extra contrast is compensated. Here is [manual for ArgyllCMS, the basis for Dispcal](http://www.argyllcms.com/doc/Scenarios.html#PM1). Most LCDs are very bad in conforming with sRGB, both white point and gamma are quite wrong.

Comment: thank you, so I guess that we are getting back at this "The default response curve is a gamma of 2.4, except for Apple OS X systems prior to 10.6 where a gamma of 1.8 is the default. **2.4** is close to that of many monitors, and **close to that of the sRGB** colorspace." mentioned in AgryllCMS documentation, and above in the main question; so in my conditions I _should_ stick to the native display gamma value.

Comment: @user124853: the display tonality almost never can be expressed in the form "a=x^2,4" (neither can sRGB tone curve be characterised so). No matter what gamma is measured, if the response does not fit in said formulae it will need significant tuning. That said, your conclusion is still valid: there is no point in making 1D LUT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37053/discussion-between-user124853-and-pinhollow-euri).

Comment: kind of strange, using gamma value as measured, I've received some wierd report values like `Maximum neutral error (@ 0.673696) = 8.987361 deltaE` and `Average neutral error = 5.002081 deltaE`. At 2.2 gamma these values are `Maximum neutral error (@ 0.673696) = 0.956004 deltaE`, `Average neutral error = 0.491909 deltaE`. [Any thoughts](https://hub.displaycal.net/forums/topic/calibration-workflow-results-thoughts/#post-2663)?

Comment: [Log file](https://hub.displaycal.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DisplayCAL-2.log) contains the following: "19:48:20,085 Target advertised gamma = 2.400000". It makes me think that DisplayCal checks against gamma 2,4 while profile is not made for this gamma. It would be nice if you uploaded the log file of another verification. I have just ran verification and I cannot find a log file to confirm it. Please screencap your verification settings.

Comment: I confirm, please find [attached file](https://hub.displaycal.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Report-at-2.2.txt). At 2.2 gamma for example, DisplayCal checks against gamma 2.2.

Comment: Getting back to the subject, in Win 10 I've successfully installed ColormunkiDisplay Software (in Win 7 there was some issues, being unable to install and use it) and I was wondering, regarding your statement "_there is a problem, **at least with DisplayCAL**: creating profile for gamma 2.2 means that 1D LUT will be created._"  If I choose 2.2 Gamma without letting the [LUT option](http://imgur.com/4pO6OLK) enabled, could be a good approach? Our concern was related to the fact that using 2.2 in dispcalGUI, will alter the color depth. Will still apply in this case too? Thanks,

Comment: @user124853: " If I choose 2.2 Gamma without letting the LUT option enabled, could be a good approach?" - I do not really know what difference should choosing some gamma value make if LUT is not created. I have Dispcal here and I can test whatever I want and answer most wuestions but Colourmunki software is totally alien to me. It may well be that it will simply fail to do accurate profile - for example, the program will rely on the chosen gamma value as accurate. And that is not impossible given that some displays are factory-calibrated and

Comment: and that Dispcal's option to use native gamma is not widely needed - people are fine with 1D LUT.

Comment: Thanks; anyway, I doubt that x-rite (the Colormunki display device producer) made a software solution that could act as a toy. I hope that this is serious :) That's why I'll stick with this for the moment because, if you remember from our last discussions, calibrating at native gamma 2.4 with DisplayCAL, I had some weird results, judging by the eye not to mention using the reports.

Comment: Using the X-rite solution the results are pretty close comparing Pshop/  Firefox / Faspictureviewer which also support color management. I'll [skip the 1D LUT](http://imgur.com/4pO6OLK) option because I have an 8bit LCD which does not have gamma correction at all, and also does not use editable internal 1D LUT.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is there is only one answer possible.  Gamma 2.2 is, was, and will be the standard.  It is the standard for sRGB in our JPG, and Windows, and HDTV, and the internet, and at our photo processing labs, etc. CRTs were 2.2, more or less, and which may be gone now, but LCD monitors have a necessary standard chip to remove the standard 2.2 gamma always found in our images.  Why fight it?  :)

"Measuring" something different probably reflects an error in the measurement process.   How do your images actually look? (when monitor is calibrated).  Gamma is brightness, and LCD monitors are notoriously way too bright by default, so 2.43 might be imaginable, but calibrate it first.

Comment: I'm trying to make a properly calibration; at this phase I just put pieces together in order to see the whole picture. thank you for your feed-back

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71821/when-should-i-use-my-displays-native-gamma-over-the-standard-2-2#comment129398_75602

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your intended use of the image.

If you intend to print it, or display it on other monitors that you know to be calibrated to a standard, you should definitely use the standard 2.2 gamma so that what you see matches closest to the final result. A fully color calibrated workflow would be even better, beyond just gamma.

If your image is to be shared to other uncalibrated monitors, i.e. the web, you have a little more leeway. The sRGB standard was developed to represent the average monitor in use at the time, and it adheres closely to a gamma of 2.2. Note that while the sRGB formula uses an exponent of 2.4, it uses some math tricks to line the curve up with a simple 2.2 gamma - don't get confused by this. I'm not aware of any surveys to see how well a typical modern monitor matches sRGB, and it's possible that your monitor is closer to average than the standard is, so leaving it at its native gamma could be acceptable.

Comment: thank you for your feed-back. Indeed the final goal is to use the monitor to create/view a future printed material or display the content on other sRGB calibrated monitors; But here we go again, according to Pinhollow Euri answer (make sense), creating 1D LUT for video card (8bit to 8bit), forcing the display to use 2.2 instead of native gamma value, will only cut the colour depth. In these conditions, which settings will be the best to use?

Comment: @user124853 you need to judge for yourself whether more accurate color rendition will be worth the tradeoff of lower color depth. My off-the-cuff answer is yes, but I've never done a rigorous comparison.

Comment: "you should definitely use the standard 2.2 gamma so that what you see matches closest to the final result. " - downvote because make zero difference in colour managed output.

Comment: @PinhollowEuri what do you think color managed output uses for a gamma standard?

Comment: @mark-ransom: there is no abstract gamma standard in colour management strictly conforming to which is obligatory for getting accurate colour. ICC profiles may have several sets of point curves which specify device behavior, like [this one](http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0320/h_1458500567_7428070_d7adf628af.png). Read more in my answer and in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37053/discussion-between-user124853-and-pinhollow-euri).