# Tagged or untagged sRGB images for web?

Tags: color-management, color-spaces

I have a situation and I am interested to find your point of view.
We have a [calibrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpU0T.jpg) monitor at D6500, tone curve as measured ~2.4, white level ~90cd/m2 and a [tagged sRGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2xAE.jpg) / [untagged sRGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lE2m.jpg) image founded on the web.

Using Firefox v46.01 browser + Color management 0.5.3.1 Extension [as attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALp90.jpg), the browser will use the default OS profile (which I think that is the new monitor .icm created/installed by the calibration software, DisplayCAL set as system default *or* sRGB(?)—please correct me if I'm wrong).

It's well known that not every browser have support for color management.
Having said that, is that a bad approach to save and use for web sRGB *untagged* images in order to have the same viewing result covering also those browsers that doesn't support color management (e.g [IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9mgk.jpg) or even Chrome—the latest versions)?

Thanks,

Comment: IIRC, most browsers will interpret images as sRGB, regardless of an embedded profile (save for the few that support colour management); thus, converting to sRGB and saving as an untagged image is probably as good as you'll get on the web, while still supporting all browsers.

Comment: This is my opinion too based on the research that I've made analysing the picture content shown on different well designed/known websites (e.g. [here](http://www.kinfolk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Kinfolk_Vol20_OntheRightTrack-3-393x500.jpg), [here](http://gallery.readcereal.com/post/145011419220), or [here](http://www.nomos-glashuette.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Images/01_NOMOS/A_Company/Image_database/Watches/Metro/Metro_Familie.jpg) and so on) but I just want to hear other thoughts maybe some cons?

Comment: @TristanSeifert Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the saying that browsers are not color managed was true a few years ago, it's no longer the case.

Firefox supports color management by default for tagged images ([source](http://cameratico.com/guides/firefox-color-management/)). The extension you're using is simply a front-end for changing the configuration more easily, it's not the actual color management engine.

Chrome is also color managed: https://photographylife.com/chrome-color-management The image in the test mentioned on the website displayed ok in IE11 as well.

So, as long as you're not using a higher gamut profile (e.g. AdobeRGB) and saving the image untagged, it should be displayed ok.

I'd be more worried however of the impact of calibrating your monitor to gamma 2.4. This makes you view the images differently than anyone else who has calibrated their monitor to 2.2 ([the sRGB gamma curve is approximately 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#/media/File:SRGB_gamma.svg))

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.Indeed,Firefox supports color management and I've used that extension to change the configuration in `about:config` section more easily.Regarding the latest versions of Chrome browsers, I suppose that there are still some limitations source [here](http://simon.tindemans.eu/cm/webcm) and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141480). IE11 should not be used for color critical work.Although it understands both ICCv2 and ICCv4 profiles, it does not use the monitor profile, which means you cannot rely on what you're seeing. Source mentioned above.

Comment: Regarding the native gamma value (2.4 in my case), creating 1D LUT for video card, forcing the display to use 2.2 instead of native gamma value, will only cut the colour depth. More details [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75575/47087);

Comment: Please note that Photographylife dot com article reffers to v22 of Chrome (2012) it's a little bit outdated. More than that Phil Newberry's comment [(april 28, 2016)](https://photographylife.com/chrome-color-management) also I think that it's not so accurate simply because the same tagged sRGB picture will look different using latest version of Chrome vs. Using Photoshop in Proof color mode (monitor profile) [please have a look](http://i.imgur.com/hoUHpZI.jpg).

Comment: Normally viewing an image in PS takes the monitor's profile into account when doing CM. Choosing proof color mode (monitor profile) is something totally different. It's the same as Proof Setup -> Custom, selecting your monitor profile and leaving _Preserve RGB Numbers_ checked, showing how it would look on that monitor if viewed with an application that doesn't do CM. Try it with an AdobeRGB image and you'll see much less saturated colors just like when you use an app without CM. I've exported the sRGB tagged image as a jpeg and opened it in Chrome. It looked the same as in PS.

Comment: Well, I've made a comparation, opening the file in Pshop and leaving it as is (tagged sRGB) without proof colors applied; As we can see, there is still a slightly color shift between what we are able to see in [Chrome (top)/ Firefox (bottom)](http://imgur.com/a/3izNn) assuming that Firefox will apply the [system default](http://i.imgur.com/t3bplFb.jpg) profile made by DisplayCAL and Photoshop.