# How to properly apply and use the monitor profile

Tags: color-management, display-calibration

I'm not so sure if I understand entirely the whole concept of applying the calibration profile or something goes wrong because:

-Using FastPicture Viewer—to open a tagged [sRGB file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2xAE.jpg)—which allows me to choose the monitor profile, the result is different comparing with what we are able to see opening the same tagged sRGB file in Photoshop using Color Proof (monitor profile) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlmKk.jpg).

Regarding the OS color management implementation, these are my settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Mbd.jpg), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckPp7.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2egzZ.jpg).
Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the source of your "B 1980 S2 #1 2016-05-25..." profile?

Comment: How it's made? Using ColorMunki display + DisplayCAL software; with [these settings](http://imgur.com/a/6tXoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the same profile in both the viewer application and the monitor's color management setting you are applying the same correction twice. Assuming the "B 1980 S2 #1 2016-05-25..." profile was generated by a monitor profiling application using a colorimeter to measure the output of your monitor, leave that profile set under your monitor's color profile in the devices tab of color management. Then select standard sRGB in the applications. When your GPU renders the image it will apply the monitor profile as the last step before sending the image to your monitor. This way all applications on your computer will receive the benefit of the color profile.

[image: Color Management/Devices]

If you wish to select a specific monitor profile in each of the applications, then you need to set the monitor profile under the devices tab of the Color Management settings to standard sRGB, since the application has already applied the color correction for your monitor. But that's kind of a roundabout way of doing it and means other applications that don't allow you to select a monitor profile won't receive the benefit of the color profile.

It appears in your case Photoshop is smart enough to figure this out and let your GPU apply the profile when sending it to your monitor. FastPicture Viewer doesn't seem to have the same capability.

Comment: Make sense somehow, these are the settings that I've made in FastPicture Viewer, Firefox and the result (Firefox vs. FastPicture Viewer vs. Photoshop) [here](https://imgur.com/a/YKdgu); My concern: is it relevant to test the picture in Photoshop using Proof colors/ Monitor RGB? I am asking because if I don't, using sRGB as colorspace (the same as the picture), it will look [different](http://i.imgur.com/au7PI1b.jpg).

Comment: Anyway it looks like Chrome still doesn't manage in a good way the sRGB [tagged profile](http://imgur.com/hoUHpZI). Can you please confirm did you read about that? [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141480) and [here](http://simon.tindemans.eu/cm/webcm) Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the part of your question that said anything about how browsers render images with or without color profiles. We've already got plenty of those questions here.

Comment: Of course it will look different if you only (correctly) apply the correction profile once. If an image is rendered correctly and you "correct" it again it will no longer be correct.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, the question about browsers was offtopic sorry but somehow related. I have another one opened [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77859/47087).

Comment: Re: "...test the picture in Photoshop using Proof colors/ Monitor RGB?" Please read D. Jurcau's comment under his answer to your other question. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/77871/15871

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40466/discussion-between-user124853-and-michael-clark).